# Jenkins - Unexpected executor death

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I see all my executors frequently changing to Dead state in one of my Jenkins slave machine(Windows 2008 R2 SP2).

Jenkins ver. 1.651.3

I have restarted Jenkins server as well as the service.

error logs-

```
Unexpected executor death
java.io.IOException: Failed to create a temporary file in /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/ABCD/jobs/EFGH/jobs/Build
    at hudson.util.AtomicFileWriter.<init>(AtomicFileWriter.java:68)
    at hudson.util.AtomicFileWriter.<init>(AtomicFileWriter.java:55)
    at hudson.util.TextFile.write(TextFile.java:118)
    at hudson.model.Job.saveNextBuildNumber(Job.java:293)
    at hudson.model.Job.assignBuildNumber(Job.java:351)
    at hudson.model.Run.<init>(Run.java:284)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild.<init>(AbstractBuild.java:167)
    at hudson.model.Build.<init>(Build.java:92)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.<init>(FreeStyleBuild.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at jenkins.model.lazy.LazyBuildMixIn.newBuild(LazyBuildMixIn.java:175)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.newBuild(AbstractProject.java:1018)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.createExecutable(AbstractProject.java:1209)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.createExecutable(AbstractProject.java:144)
    at hudson.model.Executor$1.call(Executor.java:364)
    at hudson.model.Executor$1.call(Executor.java:346)
    at hudson.model.Queue._withLock(Queue.java:1365)
    at hudson.model.Queue.withLock(Queue.java:1230)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:346)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Permission denied
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1006)
    at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:1989)
    at hudson.util.AtomicFileWriter.<init>(AtomicFileWriter.java:66)
    ... 21 more
```

[image]

I see this error log in my slave machine

```
INFO: File download attempt 1
Oct 17, 2017 10:32:00 AM com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.versioncontrol.VersionControlClient downloadFileToStreams
INFO: File download attempt 1
Oct 17, 2017 10:32:00 AM com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.client.SOAPService executeSOAPRequestInternal
INFO: SOAP method='UpdateLocalVersion', status=200, content-length=367, server-wait=402 ms, parse=0 ms, total=402 ms, throughput=913 B/s, gzip
Oct 17, 2017 10:32:00 AM com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.versioncontrol.VersionControlClient downloadFileToStreams
INFO: File download attempt 1
Oct 17, 2017 10:32:00 AM com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.versioncontrol.VersionControlClient downloadFileToStreams
INFO: File download attempt 1
Oct 17, 2017 10:32:00 AM com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.versioncontrol.VersionControlClient downloadFileToStreams
INFO: File download attempt 1
```

Comment: You said that it's a Windows slave, but the stack trace shows it trying to create a Unix file. Where has that message been generated?

Comment: This error message is from Jenkins Server Log UI

Comment: And your server is Linux right?

Comment: My Jenkins server is Ubuntu 14.04.2-server-amd64 and my slave is Windows 2008 R2

Comment: You could investigate why you're getting a
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Permission denied
When creating a temporary file in /var/lib/

Comment: @Spangen  How this will impact my slave machine to go in Dead state

Comment: Are there any logs from the slave machines them selves you could add to the original post?

Comment: I added them in original post

Comment: Same problem, same callstack.  Jenkins 2.90. However, "caused by" is different: `Input/output error`

Comment: @Kally Re "_How this_ [Permission denied] _will impact my slave machine to go in Dead state_": If a file that's necessary for a job to run on a slave can't be created due to a general, unspecific [IOException, compared to its specific derivatives](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/IOException.html), it's reasonable that the slave goes to Dead state, rather than to try again, and again, and again, and ...

Answer (score 1):

Can you please check the owner of the path /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/ABCD/jobs/EFGH/jobs/Build ? By any chance if it is created manually, you will get permission denied error if the owner is not Jenkins. Also check for free disk space on server as well as agent and try rebooting the slave agent. It has helped it at times.

Comment: `ls -l <folder >` gives the result: `total 17
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    0 Dec  1 14:17 builds
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4507 Dec  1 13:57 config.xml
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   22 Dec  1 14:15 lastStable -> builds/lastStableBuild
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   26 Dec  1 14:15 lastSuccessful -> builds/lastSuccessfulBuild
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    3 Dec  1 14:15 nextBuildNumber`
But that does not explain why restart works.

Comment: The 2 things are totally different. First is of permission denied and second is of dead slaves. Permission denied can be resolved by changing the owner to jenkins user and the dead slave issue is resolved by freeing up disk space(in case slave is running out of space) and restarting the slave.

Comment: No, there is plenty of free space.

Comment: Ok. Is the issue resolved? or are you still facing it? I guess restart resolved it.

Comment: No, it is not resolved. It happens from time to time, and I don't know 1) what causes it 2) how to prevent it. Permissions are correct, disk space is enough.

Comment: Your permissions are not set correctly. Please change the owner of the directory to jenkins user from root. Also everything under jenkins home should be owned by jenkins user, not root user. Change the owner of jenkins home directory recursively to jenkins. you can use command -- sudo chown jenkins:jenkins <JENKINS_HOME>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160705/discussion-between-amol-manthalkar-and-skyblade).

Answer (score 1):

How long are the real job names for `ABCD` and `EFGH`?

I've run into the 260 character maximum path length with Jenkins on Windows 2008 R2 before.

Answer (score 0):

The path in:

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to create a temporary file in /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/ABCD/jobs/EFGH/jobs/Build
```

with the three `/jobs` in it seems strange to me. In Jenkins it normally should rather be:

```
+- /var/lib/jenkins/jobs
   +- ABCD
   |  +- builds
   |  |  +- ...
   |  +- ...
   +- EFGH
   |  +- builds
   |  |  +- ...
   |  +- ...
   +- Build
      +- builds
      |  +- ...
      +- ...
```

Maybe there's some misconfiguration concerning paths and Jenkins tries a `mkdir /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/ABCD/jobs/EFGH/jobs/Build` and the Jenkins user or the user under which the job runs doesn't have permissions to do that.

See also [File permissions and attributes](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/File_Permissions_and_Attributes#Viewing_permissions):

> |   `w`   |   ...   | The directory's contents can be modified (create new files or folders; [...]); requires the execute permission to be also set, otherwise this permission has no effect.  |

Comment: I think the CloudBees Folder plugin organizes in "jobs" folders. I think OP may be using that or a similar plugin to organize jobs.

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, this happened because the server was very low on space.  Click on "Build Executor Status" from the dashboard and see if there is low disk space or 0 swap space. Try to free up some space. Then restart the Jenkins server / service and try again.